# CSS 2 column layout without floats

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I want quite simple thing - 2 column layout, where the right column gets the width according to its content (text) and left column takes the rest of the space.

I was able to do that using `floats` - basically the right `div` was floated to the right and the left `div` was using some `overflow: auto` magic to get the remaining area:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.ellipsize {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='right'>HELLO WORLD!!!</div>
<div class='left'>
  <div class="ellipsize">Lorizzle ipsum shiznit black amizzle, fo shizzle adipiscing tellivizzle. Nullizzle sapien velizzle, volutpat, suscipit bow wow wow, gravida i'm in the shizzle, stuff. We gonna chung i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle tortizzle. Gangster erizzle. Brizzle izzle dolizzle my shizz turpizzle tempizzle fo shizzle. Maurizzle fo shizzle nibh shizzlin dizzle gangsta. Own yo' izzle yo mamma. Yo the bizzle rhoncus away. In black habitasse platea black. Phat dapibizzle. Curabitur tellizzle urna, pretizzle eu, mattizzle pot, break yo neck, yall vitae, nunc. Mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa suscipizzle. Shizznit sempizzle fizzle shiz yo.
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I have recently read a lot of posts about how `floats` are *wrong, old-style, should not be used* and so on, and everybody says to use `display: inline-block` instead.

**Question:** is it possible to reach the same effect with `inline-block` or without `floats`?

Comment: imo, you cannot achieve the "left takes up remainder of space" effect using inline-block. I don't see anything wrong with using floats. Keep in mind, the bootstrap still builds it's grid system using floats.

Comment: Floats are fine - don't let the buzz tell you otherwise. Although flex and grid are cool for your situation that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I have recently read a lot of posts about how floats are wrong, old-style, should not be used and so on

If you're looking for a more modern solution using flexboxes is one of them. Here's how you could achive your desired effect by wrapping your content in a wrapper with a `display:flex`.

```css
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}

.right{
  background-color:pink;
}

.left{
  background-color:lightgreen
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class='right'>HELLO WORLD!!!</div>
<div class='left'>
  <div class="ellipsize">Lorizzle ipsum shiznit black amizzle, fo shizzle adipiscing tellivizzle. Nullizzle sapien velizzle, volutpat, suscipit bow wow wow, gravida i'm in the shizzle, stuff. We gonna chung i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle tortizzle. Gangster erizzle. Brizzle izzle dolizzle my shizz turpizzle tempizzle fo shizzle. Maurizzle fo shizzle nibh shizzlin dizzle gangsta. Own yo' izzle yo mamma. Yo the bizzle rhoncus away. In black habitasse platea black. Phat dapibizzle. Curabitur tellizzle urna, pretizzle eu, mattizzle pot, break yo neck, yall vitae, nunc. Mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa suscipizzle. Shizznit sempizzle fizzle shiz yo.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, I will try that, thanks! Didn't reach the `flex` "lessons" yet, I'm new as I wrote :D

Comment: No problem, flex is really good thing to learn and it's relativly easy :)

Comment: I just noticed that the right side's size is not determined by the content of the "hello world" text, so it basically didn't fully answer the question. How can I make the right part width be dynamically changed based on the width of the text to fully contain it?

Comment: If what you mean by that is that the text breaks into another line you can give it property white-space:nowrap

Answer (score 1):

use display:flex . It will work perfectly and If you want this to be responsive use flex-wrap: wrap.

```
.ellipsize {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
```